# Create an DLL written in Ada

Tags: gcc, dll, reference, ada, division

I'm trying to write an Ada DLL that just do common divison. The problem is that I cannot create the DLL since division in Ada seams to use and exception (probably checks that denominator is non-zero) and therefor gives me the following error message when I try to create the DLL:

```
C:\Programs\GPS\Math>gcc -shared -shared-libgcc -o math.dll division.o
division.o:division.adb:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to
`__gnat_rcheck_CE_Divide_By_Zero'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My divison package looks as follows:

```
-- division.ads
package Division is
   function Div
     (A : INTEGER;
      B : INTEGER)
      return INTEGER;
   pragma Export (CPP, Div);
end Division;

--division.adb
package body Division is
   function Div(A : INTEGER; B : INTEGER) return INTEGER is
      X : INTEGER := A/B;
   begin
      return X;
   end Div;
end Division;
```

Is it possible to create this DLL is some way? I'm totally new to Ada so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to create a DLL in ada is to use GNAT project files. You can see the documentation [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html#Library-Projects)

Your project (called proj_name.gpr or anything else you prefer) file looks like this:

```
library project Proj_Name is
  for Library_Name use "math";
  for Object_Dir use "obj";
  for Source_Dirs use ("src");
  for Library_Dir use "lib";
  for Library_Interface use ("Division");
  for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
end Proj_Name;
```

assuming that your sources are in a src directory, that you want object files to be compiled in the obj directory and you want to output the dll in the lib directory.

To compile the library you then have to use gnatmake : `gnatmake -P ./proj_name.gpr -p` (`-P` says what project file to use, `-p` says to create any needed directories).

On a linux it creats lib/libmath.so and should create lib/libmath.dll on a windows system.